# How select a single row october cms

Tags: mysql, sql, octobercms

How to select a single row on october cms?

How can a simple thing be so complicated here?

I thought it would be something to help us and not to disturb something that is as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM `engegraph_forms_membros`
```

Here it's like fighting against demons without a bible, oh god why?
Why make the query difficult for newbie?

Comment: To select a single row you need to use a where statement with proper conditions.

Comment: Can you show a exemple please ?

Comment: I want show all rows on my query
And i want update mydiv with then, but i dont have sucess until now, i am without any ideia how do this, i used all my newbie knowledge

Comment: Your comment "*I want to show all rows*" contradicts your question "*I want to select a single row*".

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [CSE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) if SO doesn't help :)

Comment: Sorry for my inglish horse with no name, i wanna say, that i want show one row intire, i dont seem a comando for show all columns values of a single row
ex: i have ID 1, that id have : name - age - email - phone 
in this cms i cant code a query that show all this like simple sql 
select * from (table) where id = 1 
u got it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you don't speak English natively but you should watch every single one of [these videos](https://watch-learn.com/series/making-websites-with-october-cms).

Does the record belong to a model in a plugin? Here are the docs on how to [work with models](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model).

You make a plugin, set the database which creates models, and then make components to be ran in your CMS Pages.

In a component.php file you can have something like this: Here I am calling the model class Agreements with `use Author\Plugin\Models\Agreements;`. This allows me to run a function/method to retrieve all agreements or one agreements using laravel's eloquent collection services.

Lets say we have the ID of a record. Well we can either call on the Agreements model with `::find` or with `::where`. You will noticed I have two functions that essentially do the same thing. `::find` uses the primary key of the models (in my case the id) and will return a singular record. *Note that find can take an array and return a collection of records; like `::where`. Using `::where` we are going to look for the ID. *Note `::where` always returns a collection which is why I have included `->first()`.

```
<?php namespace Author\Plugin\Components;

use Session;
use Input;
use Crypt;
use Db;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use October\Rain\Support\Collection;

use Author\Plugin\Models\Agreements;

class GetAgreement extends \Cms\Classes\ComponentBase
{
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Get one agreement',
            'description' => 'Get an agreement to change or delete it'
        ];
    }

    public function onRun() {
        $this->page['agreement'] = $this->getWithFindAgreement;
    }

    public function getWithFindAgreement() {
        $id = 1;
        $agreement = Agreements::find($id);
        return $agreement;
    }

    public function getWithWhereAgreement() {
        $id = 1;
        $agreement = Agreements::where($id)->first();
        return $agreement;
    }
}
```

If for some reason you aren't working with models, here are the docs to [work with Databases](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query). You will have to register the `use Db;` facade.

Here call the table you want and use `::where` to query it. *Note the use of `->first()` again.

```
$users = Db::table('users')->get();
$user = $users->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to select a single row:

This will give you the'first' record in the selected recordset.

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM `engegraph_forms_membros`
```

This will select all the records that meet the predicate requirement that the value of <columnname> is equal to <value>

```
 SELECT * FROM `engegraph_forms_membros` where <columnname>=<value>
```

If you select a record where multiple values meet that requirement, then you can (randomly) pick one by combining the solutions...

```
 SELECT top 1 * FROM `engegraph_forms_membros` where <columnname>=<value>
```

But be aware that without an ORDER BY clause, the underlying data is *unordered* and prone to change uncontrollably, which is why most people (including your boss) will find the use of 'Top' to be improper for real use.

Comment: i want, select and show all for now, just for know how that thing of cms works.
I want take the values of row and update mypartial to show on myDiv

Comment: i tried use select top 1, but give error on MARIA BD

Comment: SELECT * FROM `engegraph_forms_membros` WHERE id = 4

how do this on octobercms ?
I want take all the collumns values of that id row.